# does publish-item powershell command fire publish end event and can we get property like rootItem

Tags: powershell-extensions, publishing, events

```
$singleitem=get-childItem -path $RootItemPath -Language 
"en" -Recurse  | Where {$_.TemplateName -eq "TEST"} | Select-Object -first 1

publish-item -Item $singleitem -publishmode Incremental -target $publishTargets -language $language
```

Comment: Do you want to get the item after publish in a variable?

Comment: yes after the publish:end event i have a method that needs to execute, if i publish manually it works but not publishing via powershell script.

Comment: So as per your comment the publish-item doesn't publish the item?

Comment: Which Sitecore and Powershell version?